# Issue with argparse invalid choice in Python

Tags: python

When running `python test.py red`,

test.py:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from enum import Enum

Color = Enum("Color", ["red", "green," "blue"])

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("color", type=Color, choices=[c.name for c in Color])
args = parser.parse_args()
print(f"your color is {args.color}")

class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
```

I keep getting the following error, even though red is one of the options

```
usage: test.py [-h] {red,green,blue}
test.py: error: argument color: invalid Color value: 'red'
```

Have tried so many different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choices argument should be instances of `Color` to match the class specified by your `type`.

The `type` kwarg should be a function that translates from string to `Color` instance, which then must be one of your choices. Sometimes you can put the class itself, only if its `__init__` method can be used to do the conversion. Otherwise you need to use a helper function or lambda to translate from string to instance.

Try this:

```
Color = Enum("Color", ["red", "green", "blue"])

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("color", type=lambda arg: Color[arg], choices=Color)
args = parser.parse_args()

print(f"your color is {args.color}")
```

```
$ python main.py red
your color is Color.red
```

Alternatively, you could keep the argument as a string, and then convert it to a color after you finish parsing.

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("color", choices=[c.name for c in Color])
args = parser.parse_args()

color = Color[args.color]
```